# Get list of all installed Android applications, problems with getPackageManager and/or ResolveInfo?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent

*I'm working in IntelliJ, using Java, running a Pixel 2 emulator with API 30, with a project API of API 15.*

I am currently following a video tutorial on YouTube, called Make an Android App like NOVA LAUNCHER. Great tutorial so far. The video I'm stuck on is Lesson 3 of the series.
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6-cCI9Q0R0&list=PLxabZQCAe5fhGgSue40-_DjfFc_5EThhr&index=4

Skip to 9:02 to see his code in action, also shown here, copied exactly from Github.

```
    List<AppObject> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<ResolveInfo> untreatedAppList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

Here is the code that is not working for me:

```
List<AppObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> untreatedAppList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
```

I have triple checked it to make sure that I have tried direct copying and pasting, I've tried removing and swapping out the "removeApplicationContext()", and I've already browsed many other threads that also specifically recommend this code.

Whenever I run this at the end to get an idea of how many apps are recognized by my list:

```
        System.out.println("Untreated apps \n" + untreatedAppList);
```

All I get is:

```
I/System.out: Untreated apps 
[ResolveInfo{498077 com.android.settings/.Settings m=0x108000}, ResolveInfo{77a24e4 com.android.vending/.AssetBrowserActivity m=0x108000}, ResolveInfo{2975d4d injeffinitedevelopment.com/.MainActivity m=0x108000}]
```

3 items, which is Settings, Google Play, and the app I'm running.

Is the problem in the getPackageManager() or resloveInfo?... In his video he gets all of his apps. Could it be that my emulator's manifaest doesn't contain the other apps? Is it my emulator or some deeper problem than the code? What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried this on a real device? I've used the code you list in a number of Android apps.

Comment: @KevinBoone No I have not, but I do not have an android device to test it with, but I did just think of switching the emulator device. I will try that and let you know what happens.

Comment: @KevinBoone Unfortunately switching the device had no effect. Still only showing 3 apps. What file does getPackageManager() actually read from? Could I check there? I am suspect something must be wrong with how my project is built.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I used to maintain a "start menu" app for Android, that uses the same method you're using. Although it hasn't worked properly since 2015, I just tried it on my S10 and it does at least get a package list. By all means plunder m code for ideas: https://github.com/kevinboone/androidstart/blob/master/src/net/kevinboone/androidutils/MyPackageManager.java

Comment: @KevinBoone Thanks I appreciate it. Okay WIERD thing but when I use an analogous line of code for Kotlin: `val list = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)` it works perfectly. Guess Java is just cursed, so better do the project in Kotlin lol