# Getting a list of Android applications using Kotlin

Tags: android, api, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

*I am using Kotlin within IntelliJ, and **yes I've already tried this in Java with even worse results.** It only gives me 3 apps: Google Play, Go Time(The app that's currently running), and Play Store.*

I am trying to get a full list of apps on my device. When I try using intent filters, I just get the 3 apps mentioned in italics. Here is the function I am using:

```
    private fun getInstalledAppList():List<AppObject>
    {
        val list: ArrayList<AppObject> = arrayListOf()
        val untreatedAppList = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(0)
        for (untreatedApp in untreatedAppList)
        {
            if ((untreatedApp.flags and applicationInfo.flags) !== 0)
            {
                var appName: CharSequence = untreatedApp.loadLabel(packageManager)
                var appPackageName = untreatedApp.packageName
                var appImage = untreatedApp.loadUnbadgedIcon(packageManager)
                var app = AppObject(appPackageName, appName, appImage)
                println(appName)
                if (!list.contains(app)) {
                    list.add(app)
                }
            }
        }
        return list
    }
```

I get this result in the run window:

```
I/System.out: Tethering
I/System.out: Android Services Library
I/System.out: Phone and Messaging Storage
I/System.out: Dynamic System Updates
    Cell Broadcast Service
I/System.out: Calendar Storage
    com.android.providers.media
I/System.out: External Storage
I/System.out: Companion Device Manager
    MmsService
I/System.out: Download Manager
    Circular
I/System.out: Media Storage
I/System.out: Time Zone Updater
    com.android.systemui.plugin.globalactions.wallet
I/System.out: Downloads
I/System.out: Google Play Store
I/System.out: PacProcessor
I/System.out: Sim App Dialog
I/System.out: Certificate Installer
I/System.out: com.android.carrierconfig
I/System.out: Android System
I/System.out: Android R Easter Egg
I/System.out: MTP Host
I/System.out: Nfc Service
    com.android.ons
I/System.out: SIM Toolkit
    com.android.backupconfirm
I/System.out: Permission controller
    com.android.emulator.radio.config
I/System.out: Settings Storage
    com.android.sharedstoragebackup
I/System.out: SecureElementApplication
I/System.out: Input Devices
I/System.out: Emu01 display cutout
I/System.out: Markup
    com.android.cellbroadcastreceiver
I/System.out: Network manager
I/System.out: Call Management
    Rounded
I/System.out: Key Chain
I/System.out: com.android.service.ims.RcsServiceApp
I/System.out: Package installer
I/System.out: Google Play services
I/System.out: Google Services Framework
I/System.out: com.google.android.overlay.permissioncontroller
    com.google.android.overlay.emulatorconfig
I/System.out: Call Log Backup/Restore
    com.android.localtransport
I/System.out: CarrierDefaultApp
I/System.out: ProxyHandler
I/System.out: Work Setup
I/System.out: Sounds
I/System.out: Emulator Multi Display Provider
I/System.out: Presence
I/System.out: Live Wallpaper Picker
I/System.out: com.google.android.sdksetup
    com.android.server.NetworkPermissionConfig
I/System.out: Go Time
I/System.out: Settings
I/System.out: Carrier Provisioning Service
    VpnDialogs
I/System.out: Phone Services
I/System.out: Shell
    Filled
I/System.out: com.android.wallpaperbackup
I/System.out: Blocked Numbers Storage
I/System.out: User Dictionary
I/System.out: Emergency information
I/System.out: Fused Location
I/System.out: System UI
I/System.out: Bluetooth MIDI Service
I/System.out: System Tracing
I/System.out: Bluetooth
I/System.out: Contacts Storage
```

Now this is returning a bunch of system apps, which of course isn't preferred, but it still doesn't even show the user apps shown in the native app drawer such as YouTube or Clock..
[Native App Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJx4V.png)
What am I missing? I think the problem might be deeper than my code because I've seen code like mine work well with many other people and they don't seem to have my problem at all.

Please help, I've been stuck on this for the last two days. Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to get the list of applications installed on Android :

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

You will get all the necessary data in the ResolveInfo to start a application

Comment: Hi Ali, I have already used that exact same code. The only 3 apps that are returned are Settings, The app I'm running, and Google Play. You can see this in a previous question I've asked without a solution yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64165009/get-list-of-all-installed-android-applications-problems-with-getpackagemanager